# How to check whether a text is having bold in a web page

Tags: javascript, html, dom

If my html page is having lot of text and some words having formatting. If I use

```
windows.find(text);
```

It will help to find text in a web page. But how can I know the searched text is in bold in the document?

For example if my page HTML is:

```
 <body>
      Hello Techie, <b>I</b> am in bold.
 </body>
```

If I use `window.find("I am")` it will match the text. But how can I know that whether "I am" is in bold or not?

I hope question is clear. Please let me know if you want any further input to be helpful.

Comment: i guess regex expressions most be involved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`window.find()`, where supported, moves the selection to the text it has found. This being the case, you can use `document.queryCommandState()` to check the boldness of the selected content, which has the advantage of working regardless of how the boldness is set (CSS `font-weight`, `<b>` or `<strong>` elements). Unfortunately in non-IE browsers you have to temporarily put the document into design mode to make this work:

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/efN8P/

Code:

```
document.designMode = "on";
window.find("I am");
var isAllBold = document.queryCommandState("Bold");
alert(isAllBold);
document.designMode = "off";
```

Comment: Glad to have your answer. I must say this :-)

Comment: I am able to detect all the other formattings like Italics, Subscripts,Superscripts etec.. But I am unable to identify striked text. That is <s> tag. Could you please help me on this.

Comment: @So I: It's [`strikeThrough`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Rich-Text_Editing_in_Mozilla): http://jsfiddle.net/efN8P/1/.

Answer (score 3):

This works but I'm not sure about cross-browser compatibility: http://jsfiddle.net/VALr3/1/. It checks whether a `<b>` element is part of the selected elements.

```
window.find("I am");

var sel = window.getSelection(),
    frag = sel.rangeCount > 0 && sel.getRangeAt(0).cloneContents();

alert(frag && frag.querySelectorAll("b").length > 0);
```

Comment: @pimvdb Thanks for beautiful answer. But if I search only for "I" in your fiddle.. It is returning me false, even if it is having bold.Please check it here http://jsfiddle.net/VALr3/2/

Comment: @So I: It seems in that case the fragment only contains of the contents of the `<b>` tag and not the tag itself. Perhaps you can blend the other answer into this one to get the desired results.

Comment: @pimvdb I am sorry for rolling back.